# Set all bits in A which are set in B between given Lth position to Rth Position

Tags: bit-manipulation

Set all bits in Binary Representation of a number A which are set in Binary Representation of another number B between given Lth position to Rth Position.
For example:
    A= 12(1100)
    B= 11(1011)  and L=2, R=3 (position is starting from 1); then Finally
    A= 14(1110)  {set 3rd bit of A as 3rd bit of B is 1}.

It can be done simply by converting A and B to Binary Representation and setting those bits of A which are set in B with in given range.

Is there any more convenient and efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bitwise operators: 
`A | ((1 << R) - (1 << (L-1)) & B)`

Explanation: Right shift 1 by R bits to get `2^R`. Subtract it by `2^(L-1)` to get a number with of all `1`s between `L` and `R` including. Bitwise-and with `B` to get a bitmask of `B`. Bitwise-OR to set `A`s bits.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/M32DBG)